# Resetting database record Id after delete

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, uniqueidentifier

I'm currently working with a database with about 10.000+ records and growing. It's a database with maintenance logbooks on which I perform some analysis to extract some data about the maintenance. The results of the analysis are stored in the same database in a different table.

maintenance table:

```
------------------------------------------
|id      remainingdata
|1       testing
|2       alsotesting
|3       testing1
```

analysis results table:

```
------------------------------------------
|id      maintenanceid      remainingdata
|1       1                  result1
|2       1                  result2
|3       2                  result3
|4       3                  result4
|5       3                  result5
```

The logbook records can be updated after the analysis was performed, for this reason the analysis can be re-done. When a maintenance record is re-analyzed, all records of the analysis (which contain a foreign key to the maintenance record) are deleted from the table and re-entered. So let's say i re-analyze all 3 maintenance records. My results table now looks like this;

```
------------------------------------------
|id      maintenanceid      remainingdata
|6       1                  result1
|7       1                  result2
|8       2                  result3
|9       3                  result4
|10      3                  result5
```

The problem I'm facing is that when 10.000+ records are deleted and entered possible weekly, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` number gets very high very quickly. And since i want to future proof my database I need to find a solution to this problem.

NOTE: the id's in the results table are solely used to preserve duplicates, there are no references to them in other tables whatsoever.

I have thought of 2 possible solutions to this myself, both with up- and downsides to them;

1. **Change the Pk to a `BIGINT` and hope it doesnt hit the maxvalue**

Although the max value is very big there is still a risk of hitting it in the future and I don't really want to have that risk.

2. **Upon deleting any records, reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT` to the `TOP(id)`**

This seems the best solution to me but I'm interested if there are arguments against it, this would reset the id value to the max id currently in the table, if all records are re-analyzed, it would go back to 1.

I'm wondering what the opinions on my solutions are or if anyone has a better solution to this problem. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Cannot you use TRUNCATE TABLE option to reset AUTO_INCREMENT column?

Comment: @Sujith not all records are deleted always, sometimes just 1 or 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for the `BIGINT` solution. Really.

An unsigned `BIGINT` can [hold numbers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) as large as 9223372036854775807.

With the expected rate of 10k per week, it means your application is future proof for 922337203685477 weeks, or 17737253917028 years, or the lives of 221715673962 people sequentially, with the expected age of about 80 years per person. That's about three times the world population.

> there is still a risk of hitting it in the future and I don't really want to have that risk

You can be quite sure that when the limit is reached, your life is over, and the task to solve the problem is for somebody else.